# Makefile unexpected behavior after adding targets for build-release and build-debug

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, makefile

Can someone please help me fix the following makefile:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

EXEC = prog
CC   = gcc

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

.PHONY : default build-release build-debug run-release run-debug run-gdb run-valgrind clean install uninstall help

INC_DIR = ./include
SRC_DIR = ./src
OBJ_DIR = ./build
TST_DIR = ./test

CFLAGS   = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
CDEBUG   = -g -DDEBUG
CRELEASE = -O3

build-release : CFLAGS+=$(CRELEASE)
build-release : OBJ_DIR:=$(OBJ_DIR)/release
build-release : $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC)

build-debug   : CFLAGS+=$(CDEBUG)
build-debug   : OBJ_DIR:=$(OBJ_DIR)/debug
build-debug   : $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC)

default : build-release

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

# --- Linking

$(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC) : $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(OBJ_DIR)/gol.o
    $(CC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(OBJ_DIR)/gol.o

# --- Compiling

$(OBJ_DIR)/main.o : $(SRC_DIR)/main.c
    $(CC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR) -c $(SRC_DIR)/main.c

$(OBJ_DIR)/gol.o : $(SRC_DIR)/gol.c $(INC_DIR)/gol.h
    $(CC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/gol.o $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR) -c $(SRC_DIR)/gol.c

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

# --- Testing

unit_test : build/test/unit_test.o build/gol.o
    gcc -o build/test/unit_test build/test/unit_test.o build/gol.o $(CFLAGS)

build/test/unit_test.o : test/unit_test.c
    gcc -o build/test/unit_test.o -c test/unit_test.c $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR)

# --- Other targets

run-release : build-release
    $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC)

run-debug : build-debug
    $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC)

run-test : build-debug
    $(TST_DIR)/$(EXEC)

run-gdb : build-debug
    gdb $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC)

run-valgrind : build-debug
    valgrind --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --tool=memcheck $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXEC)

install: build-release
    @echo "[INSTALL] Copying executable to bin"
    cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(PROG) ~/bin/$(EXEC)

uninstall:
    @echo "[UNINSTALL] Removing executable from bin"
    rm ~/bin/$(EXEC)

clean :
    echo "[CLEAN] Removing all compiled files"
    rm build/release/* build/debug/* build/test/*

help :
    @printf "Available targets:\n\n"
    @printf "\t1. build-release\n"
    @printf "\t2. build-debug\n"
    @printf "\t3. build-test\n"
    @printf "\t4.run-release\n"
    @printf "\t5.run-debug\n"
    @printf "\t6.run-test\n"
    @printf "\t7.run-gdb\n"
    @printf "\t8.run-valgrind\n"
    @printf "\t9.run-install\n"
    @printf "\t10.run-uninstall\n"
    @printf "\t11.clean\n"
```

I am having two issues:

1. When I run `make build-release` twice in a row without changing any files, the entire code base is recompiled and relinked.
2. When I run `make run-release` the executable is not ran because the `OBJ_DIR` variable goes back to `./build` even though I append to it when `build-release` target is ran.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use make's option `-d` to see _why_ it thinks it has to build again. And `-p` shows anything make knows...

Comment: can you please make this example minimal? there seems to be a lot of irrelevant stuff that is not needed here ...

Comment: as an aside, for help target use `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)`

Comment: It seems that when I run `make release` the variable `$(OBJ_DIR)` does not get updated to `./build/release` but remains `./build` only for the target name, however, it is updated in the action

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.